# How to apply filter for 2 columns at a time in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, spreadsheet

I'm having an excel doc where it have 3 columns with some data like below

Id.   Name.    Amount

1. Suresh.  1000
2. Arun.    1000
3. Suresh.  1500
4. Arun.    1500

How to get above data like below in excel by sorting name based on a to z for specific id

Id.    Name.   Amount

1. ```
   Arun.   1000
   ```
2. ```
   Suresh. 1000
   ```
3. ```
   Arun.   1500
   ```
4. ```
   Suresh. 1500
   ```

Please help me how to get this.

Comment: Looks to me like you are first sorting on amount and then on name.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

```
[ Select 2nd & 3rd column > Data > Filter > Sort ]
```

Please share if it work/not it your case.